# Corrupted EXT4 filesystem on embedded Linux (A20 Olimex Lime 2) with clean poweroff

Tags: filesystems, ext4, embedded, corruption

### Context

I'm here to talk to you about an EXT4 filesystem issue that I don't understand.
In my company, we are working on embedded Linux system.
We use the board [Olimex Lime 2](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A20/A20-OLinuXino-LIME2/open-source-hardware).

> T2-OLinuXino-LIME2-e16Gs16M-IND

We use an image based on Olinux image ([A20-OLinuXino-bullseye-minimal-20230515-130040.img](https://images.olimex.com/release/a20/).)

Actually, we are trying to test the filesystem resistance.

#### How we do that ?

[image]

An automate drive the board AC power. It regularly power on and power off the AC.

When the Olimex Lime 2 start, it's toggling a pin out that is connected to the automate to show that it's alive and the system has booted well.

If, after 2 minutes since the power on, the system has not booted, we detect the error and stop the test.

When the automate power off the board, a script in the board run the command `poweroff` to shutdown the system (it's why there are a battery).

After 2 minutes, the automate power on the board and we repeat this cycle.

> We use a RaspberryPi to save the board logs. This Raspberry is connected with serial communication.

#### Linux image used

Our image is composed with three partition (all in ext4) :

- `boot` : Contains the kernels and it's assets
- `root` : The main filesystem
- `data` : To store data (ex : logs)

The first two are in read only mode. Only the third allow read and write.

We mainly use Docker to deploy and execute our applications.

### The problem :(

After a half day, the partition `data` seem corrupted and the system starts in emergency mode.

```
[FAILED] Failed to start File Systeâ¦ck on /dev/disk/by-label/data.
See 'systemctl status "systemd-fsck@devâ¦y\\x2dlabel-data.service"' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/data.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
         Starting Load AppArmor profiles...
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[  OK  ] Finished Set console font and keymap.
[  OK  ] Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[  OK  ] Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[  OK  ] Finished Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[FAILED] Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
See 'systemctl status apparmor.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started ifup for eth0.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[  OK  ] Finished Raise network interfaces.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenance
```

[Full logs here](https://filebin.net/8kqogolik32sj21t/log2.txt)

#### FSCK

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34                                                 
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)                                               
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes                                
Pass 2: Checking directory structure                                      
Directory inode 170220, block #0, offset 0: directory has no checksum.    
Fix? no                                                                   
                                                                          
Directory inode 170220, block #0, offset 0: directory corrupted           
Salvage? no                                                               
                                                                          
e2fsck: aborted                                                           
                                                                          
data: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

#### DEBUGFS

```
#> sudo debugfs -R 'ncheck 170220' /dev/sdk3                                                   
                                                                                                 
debugfs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)                                                                                                 
Inode   Pathname                                                                                                             
170220  /system/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/b5fe77bd4ece5a7f9ed642c1efc878aaddf4e9c9b49514e1ab0e9799505be38d
```

#### Others details

- We are two boards in test who used the **same** image, one we use an SD card and an other that we use embedded emmc.
  The problem occurs **ONLY** on the SD card board.
- Before the last power off (before that the board doesn't start correctly), we have a kernel logs about the ext4 fs error :

```
a20-olinuxino login: [   34.961248] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p3): __ext4_find_entry:1547: inode #170220: comm0
```

---

I don't understand this error, can you help me please ?

Have a great day !

Comment: Hardware error (heat, condenser?)

Comment: Ok but can you specify your idea please ? There are no heat issue and I don't understand what you mean by *condenser* ?

Comment: You wrote "After a half day"... And the difference is hardware based. 1st thing then the physical problem. For me... (condensator, sorry)

Comment: I think that it's possible but I would like to know why exactly ? I can imagine that it's very complicated to know that but with a bit of luck somebody have already meet a similar issue. And about condensator, I don't know sorry..

Comment: Just an idea to help your problem-solving.

Comment: @Julien I think K-attila was referring to a "capacitor". However, a few other details would be good to know: (1) Does the eMMC-based board use the _exact_ same OS image (i.e both copied from the same source) as the SD-card-based board? (2) What happens if you exchange the SD-card? (3) I'm not too familiar with the board, but do both have the option to use eMMC as well as SD-Card? If so, what happens if you boot the one currently using eMMC from an SD-card instead?

Comment: (1) Yes they use the **exact** same OS image. (2) I tried with few SD card and the problem persists. I only could test with *MLC* SD card because I don't have *SLC* SD card.  (3) Yes, both can it, but the problem persists for a board who use a SD card.

Comment: Today's eMMC are MLC, too. Perhaps used in PSLC mode. Sure, SDcards are not made for this purpose, but I don't expect the problem there, but rather in a wrong power down sequencing, because the error happends at power down. For example, the unmounting of the file systems could be triggered, but the supply for the external SDcard switched off before the sync is completed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Our hardware engineer has the same theory as yours about a bad powerdown sequence. Actually we don't have a solution to the SD card problem and we are stopping our research for a solution because eventually we will use the eMMC for production.